# SQL Simple Join Query

Tags: sql, scala, join, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I start by saying that I am new to SQL so the question may be trivial.
I have two tables with a time-stamp key.
For each event `t_i` in `table 1` I want all the events `q` in `table 2` such that :

```
q.timeStamp < t_i.timeStamp and q.timeStamp > t_{i-1}.timeStamp
```

That is to say, if events happen according to time stamp in this order:

```
    q1
t1  q2
    q3
    q4
t2  q5
    q6
t3  q7
```

then the resulting query should be:

```
t1: q1
t2: q2 q3 q4
t3: q5 q6
```

I am using Scala with SQL Spark with DataSet and DataFrame classes, so either a pure functional 'groupBy' or a SQL query would be good.

Comment: We need sample data - show us how your underlying dataset looks (in a way that we can copy paste into our own shells). Otherwise we don't know how to properly transform your data!

Comment: I haven't reported the data because I wrapped it in multiple case classes for easier manipulations. So I will paste the raw data

Comment: @KatyaHandler I just added a snapshot of the data. In the original dataset the DATE field changes as well and should be considered in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First , it's not really a very "Simple" query...

First - let's create dataframes with some sample data - I created small case classes with only time and a string value, you can replace them with more elaborate classes:

```
case class A(time: Long, aValue: String)
case class B(time: Long, bValue: String)

val tableA = Seq(A(1, "q1"), A(2, "q2"), A(3, "q3"), A(4, "q4"), A(5, "q5"), A(6, "q6"), A(7, "q7"))
val tableB = Seq(B(2, "t1"), B(5, "t2"), B(7, "t3"))

val dfA: DataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(tableA)
val dfB: DataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(tableB)
```

Now - two alternatives (which are conceptually identical):

1. **Using SQL**:

   ```
   dfA.registerTempTable("a")
   dfB.registerTempTable("b")

   sqlContext.sql(
     """
       |SELECT collect_list(c.time), collect_list(c.aValue), first(b.time), first(b.bValue)
       |FROM (
       |  SELECT FIRST(a.time) as time, FIRST(a.aValue) as aValue, MIN(b.time) AS bTime
       |  FROM a
       |  JOIN b ON b.time > a.time
       |  GROUP BY a.time) AS c
       |JOIN b ON c.bTime = b.time
       |GROUP BY b.time
     """.stripMargin).show()
   ```

   which would print, for each value of b (time and bValue) a list of times and a list of values of a.
2. **Using DataFrames**:

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

   val aWithMinB: DataFrame = dfA
     .join(dfB, dfA("time") < dfB("time"))
     .groupBy(dfA("time"))
     .agg(first(dfA("aValue")), min(dfB("time")))
     .withColumnRenamed("FIRST(aValue)", "aValue")
     .withColumnRenamed("min(time)", "bTime")

   aWithMinB
     .join(dfB, dfB("time") === aWithMinB("bTime"))
     .groupBy(dfB("time"))
     .agg(collect_list(aWithMinB("time")), collect_list(aWithMinB("aValue")), first(dfB("time")), first(dfB("bValue")))
     .show()
   ```

Notice that both would only work with Spark 1.6.0 or later, since `collect_list` doesn't exist in earlier versions.

**UPDATE**: some explanation of the flow here:

- The first query (*inner* query in SQL version) is meant to create a "common value" for all records in table `a` that should be *grouped* into a single record in the result
- What's that common value? Values in `a` that should be grouped are values between two consecutive records in `b`. So, they share the same *minimum* value of `b.time` that is *greater* then their time. In other words - for each time X in `a` we look for the *smallest* time in `b` that is greater than X. That would be **the same value** for all records in `a` between two consecutive `b`s
- To achieve that, we JOIN `a` with `b` with the condition of `b.time > a.time` (getting many records of `b` for each record of `a`), and then group by `a.time` (shrinking the result back to one record per record in `a`), taking the *minimum* `b.time` for each such record and the *first* value of each `a` column (taking the first doesn't really matter - all grouped records have the same value for all of `a`'s columns!)
- Now that we have this "extra info" for each record in `a`, we join it with `b` on `time` column and group by that column. All `a` records with same `bTime` will be joined to the corresponding `b` record, and we're done: we use `first` again for all of `b`'s columns (again, all values are the same for all grouped records because we group on `b`'s unique identifier), and use `collect_list` on `a`'s columns to get all values as a list.

Comment: this works but the reasoning behind it is unclear to me as I do not have previous experience with SQL, would you be able to explain it to me?

Comment: added a detailed explanation, hope this helps. If not, sorry :( take an SQL tutorial to understand the logical meaning of join, where, group...